# NavigationBar bar, tint, and title text color in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios8, uinavigationbar

The background text in the status bar is still black. How do I change the color to white?

```
// io8, swift, Xcode 6.0.1 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orangeColor()]

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 333, accepted):

In **`AppDelegate.swift`**, in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` I put the following:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 46.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

(For Swift 4 or earlier use `NSAttributedStringKey` instead of `NSAttributedString.Key`)

For `titleTextAttributes`, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes) say:

> You can specify the font, text color, text shadow color, and text
>   shadow offset for the title in the text attributes dictionary

Comment: what if we have mutiple navigation bars ?

Comment: tintColor doesn't work for Xcode 7.3.1. The text is still black.

Comment: In Xcode 8.2, the titleTextAttributes does not autocomplete but it works.

Comment: is barTintColor still necessary? deleting that line still works

Comment: This is adding a text attribute. Not actually changing the color of the title. If you note the font of the text you can understand the difference.

Comment: @Albert Vila Calvo in iOS 15 this thing is not working, can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 130):

I like Alex's answer. If you want something quick to try out in a `ViewController` make sure you use

```
viewWillAppear()
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
    nav?.tintColor = UIColor.white
    nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
    //nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange] // swift 4.2
}
```

[image]

Comment: But I'm using iso 8.1

Comment: why viewWillAppear()? I am doing this in viewDidLoad and it works fine.

Comment: Because every time you view the UIView you'd like it to be set. If you set in viewDidLoad() say in a UITabBar view, move to another tab where it's set again, then come back it'll be overwritten as the original view was only loaded once.

Comment: Yes, either you put your setting value in UINavigationController ViewDidLoad or you put these setting value in UIViewController ViewWillApear function, both work for me

Comment: Update for swift 4 - `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` should now be `NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor`

Comment: **NOTE:** this will change the title color for all controllers, even the parent. If you want the parent to still retain it's color, you can do so in the `willMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)` function of the child

Comment: Update for Swift 4.2: `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` instead of `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`

Comment: This is adding a text attribute. Not actually changing the color of the title. If you note the font of the text you can understand the difference.

Answer (score 82):

To change the color universally, this code should sit in the `NavigationController`'s `viewDidLoad` function:

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Status bar white font
        self.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

To change it per `ViewController` you would have to reference the `NavigationController` from the `ViewController` and write similar lines in that `ViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` function.

Comment: How do I override the NavigationController to use these methods?

Comment: You don't override the NavigationController, you just modify it in the ViewDidLoad function. I updated my answer above.

Comment: So a developer just has to add NavigationController.swift to the workspace? If so that is neat!

Comment: @AG1 This is incorrect, just adding a new file NavigationController.swift is not enough, you have to hook up your Navigation Controller in the Storyboard to this file in the Identity Inspector since by default it will use a Generic UINavigationController.

Comment: You can also just do all of this in the storyboard w/out needing to create a custom navigation controller. The properties for Bar Tine and Style are right there on the right under the Attributes inspector.

Answer (score 38):

**Swift 5**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

**Swift 4**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: I get: Type 'NSAttributedStringKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'foregroundColor'

Comment: Please use below code for latest version xcode 10 and swift 4.2
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

Answer (score 17):

To work in **objective-c** I have to put the following lines in `viewWillAppear` in my CustomViewController.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

For **Swift2.x** this works:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

For **Swift3.x** this works:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

Comment: But when I go back to another viewcontroller the color has changed also. Any idea on how to prevent this. I want mine main viewcontroller to be one color and the others another.

Comment: I think you also have to set the color in your new view controller.

Answer (score 15):

**To do this job in storyboard (Interface Builder Inspector)**

With help of `IBDesignable`, we can add more options to Interface Builder Inspector for `UINavigationController` and tweak them on storyboard. First, add the following code to your project.

```
@IBDesignable extension UINavigationController {
    @IBInspectable var barTintColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            navigationBar.barTintColor = newValue
        }
        get {
            guard  let color = navigationBar.barTintColor else { return nil }
            return color
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var tintColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            navigationBar.tintColor = newValue
        }
        get {
            guard  let color = navigationBar.tintColor else { return nil }
            return color
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var titleColor: UIColor? {
        set {
            guard let color = newValue else { return }
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color]
        }
        get {
            return navigationBar.titleTextAttributes?["NSForegroundColorAttributeName"] as? UIColor
        }
    }
}
```

Then simply set the attributes for UINavigationController on storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In Swift5 and Xcode 10

```
self.navigationItem.title = "your name"
let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to set the tint color and bar color for the entire app, the following code can be added to AppDelegate.swift in

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

    var navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()

    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)
    navigationBarAppearace.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.76, green:0.40, blue:0.40, alpha:1.0)
    navigationBarAppearace.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    return true
`
```

[Navigation barTintColor and tintColor is set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvjaZ.png)

Answer (score 6):

Updated with swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5.1**

Only copy and Paste in `ViewDidLoad()` and Change its and size as your need.
Before copy and paste add Navigation Bar on top of the Screen.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "TitilliumWeb-Bold.ttf", size: 16.0)!, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

If it not work then you can try for only change its text color

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4.2 version of Albert's answer-**

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 234.0/255.0, green: 46.0/255.0, blue: 73.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

Comment: I really liked how you added this answer.  .barTintColor isn't an option now.  Do you mean .backgroundColor?

Answer (score 4):

Setting text color of navigation bar title to white in Swift version 4.2:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.1

Add a func to viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  setup()
}
```

In the `setup()` function add:

```
func setup() {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackOpaque
        navigationItem.title = "YOUR_TITLE_HERE"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
        let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = attributes
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom color to `TitleText` at `NavigationBar`, here a simple and short code for Swift 3:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

or

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName :UIColor.white]
```

Answer (score 1):

in Swift 4.2

```
var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
nav?.tintColor = UIColor.white
nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift up through Swift 3.2 (not Swift 4.0)

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]

    // unconfirmed but I assume this works:
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.black
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 this works:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue]
```