# Change Safari View Controller Done Button tint?

Tags: ios, swift

I can change bottom UI bar with:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Can't locate how to do same with top-right "Done" button.

Here's where that works in AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()

    return true
}
```

Adding this does not work:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26008551/4475605

Comment: @AdrianB Couldn't get that to work before. Maybe because this is new rev in 9.

Answer (score 2):

To change de Done button color and also the bottom UI bar you have to set the tintColor property of the SFSafariViewController's view

example:

```
let webVC = SFSafariViewController(URL: yourURL)
webVC.view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ismael's answer didn't work in iOS 10 for me. Since iOS 10 `SFSafariViewController` has a property `preferredControlTintColor` to set the color of the buttons. Another new property is `preferredBarTintColor` fyi.

This is my approach in Swift 3:

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: "<YOUR_URL_STRING>")!)

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    svc.preferredControlTintColor = UIColor.red
} else {
    svc.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
}

self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me in iOS 10. Only affects the bottom toolbar's button.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this works:

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PetroKorienev What's not clear to you? The code that works is there.

Comment: It is not the solution, because your code works for EVERY button in the app, and it is not good solution.

Comment: @Bartłomiej Semańczyk That was my intent—every button.

Comment: @EricD That was my intent—every button.

Comment: @user1452893 people are such sticklers on stackoverflow. Thanks for the answer. Helped me. Not everybody is browsing these questions for an exact answer.

Comment: @AlexanderMacleod Glad it helped. Eventually, it get upvoted to at least a zero ;)