# how do i change the navigation bar title color in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationbarappearance

Im not sure how to change the color of the following nav bar title:

with the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let navigationBarAppearace = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor(red: 150/255, green: 150/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1)
}
```

i am able to change the color of "Upload Post" and "Share"

but im not sure how to change the middle title "Upload Post" to a different color

[image]

how do i change the color to white for example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NavigationBar bar, tint, and title text color in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008536/navigationbar-bar-tint-and-title-text-color-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 2):

Title color can be changed from Storyboard. Tapp on navigation bar in your navigation View controller and change in attribute inspector

[image]

or you can do it programmatically in your view controller ViewDIDLOAD

if you prefer large title

```
 navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

or

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

Answer (score -3):

let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.lightGray]
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes