# SearchController not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7

Suppose, I am in discuss view controller and I searched something. Now I switched the tab and now again I get back to this discuss view controller then navigation bar got hidden which i don't want. I tried everything, like hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation or setHidden property of navigation item, but nothing is happening.

Comment: show us some code during tabswitching from search & viewdidappear / viewwillappear portion of discuss view controller

Answer (score 1):

try this

> if your current viewcontroller is already embed with Navigation controller, the following code will work

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
   [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];

}
```

**Note**

> Present viewcontroller does not embed with `UINavigationcontroller`, if you want we need to add in manual, see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724194/presentviewcontroller-and-displaying-navigation-bar) once