# Popup not working from inside Alert in code

Tags: swift, popup, alert

I am creating alert from trailing swipe in a tableview. 
On clicking Edit, i am trying to instantiate another view controller and show it as a popup.

The problem is that Popup is either showing in the same screen or when it shows as a popup is missing the navigation bar.

I looked into different threads on stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.

On a different screen, this works perfectly when i set up the view controller to show as a popup from the storyboard but i can't figure out how to get this to work from inside Alert.

I added the core part of the code that doesn't work. Happy to add any other details you need to look into this.

What I tried so far :

1) Setup presentation style for the vc

vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

2) Try a transition -- This displays the vc in the same window

```
            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.5
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
            transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
            transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
            self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
```

3)    Result is same as #2

self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: false)

4) Self.Present without the navigation controller.

```
let modifyAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title:  "Manage", handler: { (ac:UIContextualAction, view:UIView, success:(Bool) -> Void) in
            print("Update action ...")


            let alert = UIAlertController()

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                    print("User click Edit button")

                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ManageCategoryViewController") as! ManageCategoryViewController

                vc.selectedIdx = indexPath.row
                vc.categoryListArray = self.categoryListArray
                vc.type = "update"
                //vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover

                /*
                let transition = CATransition()
                transition.duration = 0.5
                transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
                transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
                transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromTop
                self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
                */

                self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: false)

            }))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                print("User click Cancel button")
            }))

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                print("completion block")
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

On Further reading and trying multiple options, I was able to this issue is not due to the popover being initiated from inside the alert.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_transient_content_in_a_popover

If you need the navigation controller, you can add a navigation controller as suggested in one of the answers in the post below.

[presentViewController and displaying navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724194/presentviewcontroller-and-displaying-navigation-bar)

Posting the code incase it is useful to someone.

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
                self.navigationController?.present(navController, animated: true) {
                     // The popover is visible.
                }
```